# How to get list of available output audio source ( Speaker, earphone, bluetooth )

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, avaudiosession

like title, i'd like to know how can i get list of available output sound route for my voip app, or reproduce default IOS effect. At this moment i can enable/disable speaker when the user make call but if the user have a connected bluetooth earphone, i'd like that user can selecting which route use to default output source.
if the user have bluetooth device connected user can do this select, only speaker output otherwise.

Any suggestion, link or tutorial is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of all the outputs using `AVAudioSession`'s `currentRoute`, like so:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSLog(@"Outputs: %@", [[session currentRoute] outputs]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 4**

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
// outputs contains all current outport 
let outputs = audioSession.currentRoute.outputs
```